# My ajax code can't send values to other php page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I tested my update.php file and it works perfect and there is not any error when i checked my script via console . Only problem in here . Ajax can't send values "id" "comment_area" to update.php file . What is the mistake in here ?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b_news").submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var text = $('#breaking_news_text').val();
    var id = 21;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "update.php",
      data: {
        comment_area: text,
        id: id
      },
      success: function() {
        alert("sucess");
      }
    });
  });
});



</script>
```

```html
<form id="b_news" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <div>
      <textarea id="breaking_news_text" class="breaking_news_text" rows="6" cols="50" placeholder="Add text here..." required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>

    <input type="button" id="save" value="Save Changes" />

  </div>
</form>
```

```html
<?php 
include("./inc/connect.inc.php");

$id=$_POST['id'];
$update = $_POST['comment_area'];
$sql = "update comments set comment_area='$update' Where id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)or die("error");

     


?>
```

Comment: show the php code. done any basic debugging? maybe there's a redirect and your script is being called as a GET, and the post values are lost.

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $_POST)` and see what comes up. And note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Try to debug by putting this in your PHP script, `var_dump($_POST)` and make sure you see those two params.

Comment: try sending your data serialised. `data: comment_area=${text}&id=${id}`

Comment: Just FYI, your PHP file is very insecure.  What if I sent you a POST request with an `id` of `' OR ''='`?

Comment: string 'GET' (length=3)
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: i know it is insecure . I just practicing ajax .

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to submit the form.  `<input type="button" />` has no default action and won't fire the `submit` handler.

Comment: @Uzi — Manually serializing the data is simply error prone code that is harder to read. Don't do that.

Comment: what should i do to submit it

Comment: enter key didn't work . What i need to do . What ashould i change in html file .

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your button simply can't submit the form because of its type.
Try to change the type attribute of the button to submit this way :

```
<input  type="submit" id="save" value="Save Changes"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First **you can only have one script per script element**. The script can either be referenced by the `src` attribute or it can be between the start and end tags.

If you try to do both, as you are here, then only the `src` will be respected.

Use separate `<script>` elements for your two scripts.

---

Second, **you have no way to trigger the submit event**. The submit event will trigger when the form is submitted, but you can't do that from a textarea or a button. Replace the button with a submit button.

Comment: Forms can be submitted without any buttons present though. Try selecting the input field & hitting enter in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwLsuapj/).

Comment: Isn't that why he mentions the `textarea`?

Comment: @Siguza — They can, but as I said in the answer, the form in the question only has a textarea and a button. It doesn't have a text input.

Comment: it gives error if i remove src .

Comment: @anor — What error? Is it complaining that `$` isn't defined? That's because you need to load jQuery before running your own script. Previously you were loading jQuery and not running your own script at all. You need two script elements as I said in the answer.

Comment: ah thank you so much guys it works perfect

Comment: what a stupid mistake took my hours to fix . <3 all